# what is DDODBC.DAT

Tags: linux, perl, odbc

The file /var/local/odbc/DDODBC.DAT is being created/accessed on some (not all) servers when the database is accessed via Perl dbi:ODBC.

I did a full crawl through /var/local/odbc on a server that does create the file and a server that does not, and everything is identical (md5sum) save for the existence of that file.  There is no difference in the environment and the odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files are also the same.

I'm currently at a loss.  I'm interested because this file caused a db issue that was resolved by force-removing this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686610/perl-dbiodbc-crashing-using-strange-file/9788449).

> DataDirect has confirmed that the file DDODBC.DAT is (typically)
>   created when there is a licensing conflict on the host. In our case,
>   our license is for servers with a maximum of 16 CPUs, however we
>   installed the driver on a host with 24 CPUs. The driver realized this,
>   made note of it (with DDODBC.DAT), and will, eventually, switch itself
>   into evaluation mode.